# Is it possible a table with a common values but only one column has diferent data to make it like pivot in a single line?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following data.

```
PLU_ID DESCRIPTION PLU_REFERENCE
----------------------------------
1       ITEM 1     0001
1       ITEM 1     AZ.12345 
1       ITEM 1     OP-09-AZX
2       ITEM 2     ABCD123
2       ITEM 2     1234567
```

What I want is a result like

```
PLU_ID DESCRIPTION PLU_REFERENCE  PLU_REFERENCE  PLU_REFERENCE
----------------------------------
1       ITEM 1     0001           AZ.12345       OP-09-AZX
2       ITEM 2     ABCD123        1234567
```

Every item can have multiple references. I tried to pivot the table but it didn't work as I want.

How can i achive this result set?

Comment: First, you encourage others to help by formatting your question so that it is easily read - thank your editor. Next, you encourage others to help EVEN MORE by providing information that is easily consumed by others to experiment and demonstrate. Your first suggestion does that - but that burden should be yours. Lastly, "didn't work as I want" is NEVER a useful thing to post. Post your attempt, the result, and then identify why actual result does not match your desired result. If an errors occurs, post everything about the error exactly as received.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
with tbl_cte(PLU_ID, [DESCRIPTION], PLU_REFERENCE, rn) as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by PLU_ID order by PLU_REFERENCE)
    from (values (1, 'ITEM 1', '0001'), (1, 'ITEM 1', 'AZ.12345'), (1, 'ITEM 1', 'OP-09-AZX'),
                 (2, 'ITEM 2', 'ABCD123'), (2, 'ITEM 2', '1234567')) v(PLU_ID, [DESCRIPTION], PLU_REFERENCE))
select t.PLU_ID, [DESCRIPTION], 
       max(case when rn=1 then PLU_REFERENCE else null end) PLU_REFERENCE1,
       max(case when rn=2 then PLU_REFERENCE else null end) PLU_REFERENCE2,
       max(case when rn=3 then PLU_REFERENCE else null end) PLU_REFERENCE3
from tbl_cte t
group by PLU_ID, [DESCRIPTION]
order by PLU_ID;
```

```
PLU_ID  DESCRIPTION PLU_REFERENCE1  PLU_REFERENCE2  PLU_REFERENCE3
1       ITEM 1      0001            AZ.12345        OP-09-AZX
2       ITEM 2      1234567         ABCD123         NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's not how the pivot works, we use pivot to convert columns and rows, in your case, I wrote a pivot query, couldn't get your desired result, but that's what pivot gives you.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT  @cols =  STRING_AGG(val, ',') FROM (SELECT DISTINCT val = QUOTENAME(PLU_REFERENCE) FROM #PLU) t

set @query = 'SELECT PLU_ID, DESCRIPTION, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select PLU_ID, DESCRIPTION, PLU_REFERENCE from #PLU
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(PLU_REFERENCE)
                for PLU_REFERENCE in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '
EXEC (@query)
```